# C# library for converting json schema to sample JSON

Tags: json.net, swagger, jsonschema

I'm looking for a C# library that will generate a valid JSON object based on a given JSON Schema.  I'd like to produce a very simple JSON sample just like how [Swagger](https://swagger.io/) does it:

[image]

I've seen some JavaScript libraries like [JSON Schema Faker](http://json-schema-faker.js.org), but I need a C#/.Net library where I can generate sample JSON in my backend code.

Comment: I wrote a simple one, I just need to find a way of making it OSS.  It's not that hard to get something simple working.  Let me see if I can get a snippet of code that will get you started.

Comment: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, it is super simplistic and doesn't take into account many factors of JSON schema, but it might be a good enough starting point for you.  It also depends on the JsonSchema library from Newtonsoft.

```
   public class JsonSchemaSampleGenerator
    {
        public JsonSchemaSampleGenerator()
        {
        }

        public static JToken Generate(JsonSchema schema)
        {
            JToken output;
            switch (schema.Type)
            {
                case JsonSchemaType.Object:
                    var jObject = new JObject();
                    if (schema.Properties != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var prop in schema.Properties)
                        {
                            jObject.Add(TranslateNameToJson(prop.Key), Generate(prop.Value));
                        }
                    }
                    output = jObject;
                    break;
                case JsonSchemaType.Array:
                    var jArray = new JArray();
                    foreach (var item in schema.Items)
                    {
                        jArray.Add(Generate(item));
                    }
                    output = jArray;
                    break;

                case JsonSchemaType.String:
                    output = new JValue("sample");
                    break;
                case JsonSchemaType.Float:
                    output = new JValue(1.0);
                    break;
                case JsonSchemaType.Integer:
                    output = new JValue(1);
                    break;
                case JsonSchemaType.Boolean:
                    output = new JValue(false);
                    break;
                case JsonSchemaType.Null:
                    output = JValue.CreateNull();
                    break;

                default:
                    output = null;
                    break;

            }


            return output;
        }

        public static string TranslateNameToJson(string name)
        {
            return name.Substring(0, 1).ToLower() + name.Substring(1);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much.   Exactly what I needed to get going.

Comment: Very useful, was able to use OpenAPI.Net to read a swagger.json file and the code above to convert schemas to json examples.   I changed the use of JsonSchema to OpenApiSchema, it was easy enough to get working.